# How can I implement pseudo-dynamic css?

Tags: javascript, css

Im having trouble with managing custom colored elements on the page.

For example, we have 100 navigation squares on the page, each one has its own color, cant think of any way except of creating css classes for each type of color. Which will produce LOTS of css code.

Need some help with this,
Thanks

*added javascript & jquery tags as one of the possible ways of solving this question

**Update:**
Thanks for responses guys, feeling like I need to get into details.
Im having squared category navigation on my search page, colors can go from server side or can be stored in client's js.
Im getting list of categories from server (lets assume im getting color for each one too)
Then Im building all squares (they are white by default, but on :hover they change their color)
So I would go for such solution:

```
<ul id="squares">
<li class="greencolor"></li>
<li class="redcolor"></li>
<li class="bluecolor"></li>
</ul>
```

with css:

```
#squares li.redcolor:hover{
 background:red;
}
#squares li.greencolor:hover{
 background:green;
}
#squares li.bluecolor:hover{
 background:blue;
}
```

Hopefully now you can see what I was talking about referring tons of css code for 100 elements.

And yes, I understand that I can go for such solution:

```
var colorsMap={'redcolor':'red','greencolor':'green'};     
$('#squares li').on('hover',function(e){

    $(this).css('background-color', colorsMap[$(this).attr('class')];

});
```

but this doesnt sound as an elegant solution to me and Im trying to find way to make it through css, not inline css changes by js

Comment: And what is wrong with lots of css code compared to lots of js code other than the fact that css will work in all modern browsers without normal users having the ability (or reason) to turn it off?

Comment: javascript is no shortcut to css. it only gives you the ability to do something dynamically and on the fly. The only way you can have it shorter in javascript is that your color of the next square is mathematical achievable from the actual color. Then you could loop through and would have only one relative (depending on the algorithm) short loop to add the styles.

Comment: You mean each square should have an unique color?

Comment: Are the colors specified, our can they be randomized?

Comment: 100 navigation elements (in 100 different colors) sounds excessive.  Perhaps you should rethink the design.  If the colors are coming from the server side (eg. stored in a database), then inline styles would be the way to go.

Comment: thanks for responses, added my update, hopefully its more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I recommend to use CSS to achieve it, but there's still a solution better than inline style:

```
var selector = '#squares li'
  , css = []
  , style = document.createElement( 'style' )
  , colorsMap= {
      'redcolor': 'red',
      'greencolor': 'green',
      'bluecolor': 'blue'
    }
$( selector ).each( function() {
  css.push( selector + 
            '.' + 
            // recommand to use data-attr to store color info
            // assuming `className == 'bluecolor'`
            this.className + 
            ':hover' +
            '{' +
            'background:' +
            colorsMap[ this.className ] +
            '}'
            )
})
style.textContent = css.join('')
document.head.appendChild( style )
```

By dynamic insert CSS into `<head>`, you still get the benefits from normal CSS, [demo](http://jsbin.com/urokud/1/edit).

And, you also can generate dynamic CSS file in back-end side, it's more easier to manage colors, by a configuration form or something else.

Answer (score 0):

First,my English is poor(But I'm trying my best to learn).So I can't say that I understand you clearly.But what you say let me think of the chooser.I didn't know if it is you want,but I think it's not a bad idea. Just like these:
    
    `$(":header").css("color","#FF00FF");

    $("div:contains('test')").css("background","#666600");

    $("div:empty").css("background","#888800");

    $("div:has(span)").css("background","#008080");`
     etc.
Their role's I won't say it.I think it nessary for to learn, they are very useful.